# Java Jade : not displaying in console

Tags: java, agents-jade

I begun learning Jade platform, I created a first simple agent but it doesn't display anything in the console.

```
package firstJade;

import jade.core.Agent;

public class firstAgent extends Agent {

    @Override
    protected void setup(){
        System.out.println("hello Jade !");
        System.out.println("my agent name is " + getLocalName());
        doDelete();
    }
}
```

After running the Jade remote window does open but the messages in my code doesn't appear

> INFOS: --------------------------------------
>
> ### Agent container Main-Container@192.168.1.81 is ready.

Comment: How do you invoke the jade agent in the ui?

Comment: by the jade.Boot in configuration: "-gui jade.Boot  firstAgent:firstJade.firstAgent"

Comment: If you are running from eclipse them it might be that eclipse is incorrectly identifying the path of the agent class.

Comment: sometimes when I execute again it gave me this error "GRAVE: Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active" but if I reopen Eclipse it's gone and open the RMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are incorrect. if you are running from eclipse than try below;

```
-gui firstAgent:firstJade.firstAgent
```

or

```
-gui -agents firstAgent:firstJade.firstAgent
```

If you run it from command line then you will need to add `jade.Boot` main class name after `-cp classpath` but before `-gui` option.

Comment: thank you @Setu, could you please give me a tutorial about how to configure eclipse if I have more than one agent ?

Comment: pretty simple. The agents can be in the form of comma separated values i.e `-gui firstAgent:firstJade.firstAgent;secondAgent:firstJade.secondAgent;thirdAgent:thirdJade.thirdAgent`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your java class with main method and run it to start your agent.

```
String[] args1 = {"-gui","ClusteringAgent:multi.agent_clustering.ClusteringAgent"};

            jade.Boot.main(args1);
```

That is

```
String[] args1 = {"-gui","Agent Name:package.Agent-class-name"};

 jade.Boot.main(args1);
```

You can even add agent in containers by making following changes:

```
String[] args1 = {"-container","ClusteringAgent:multi.agent_clustering.ClusteringAgent"};

            jade.Boot.main(args1);
```

By replacing -gui with  -container.
But make sure you have added your first agent with jade GUI before adding subsequent agents in new containers.